# Create new pst file if current file size reaches 2 GB

Tags: powershell, outlook

I want to schedule a Powershell script that checks the size of current pst file daily. If it reaches 2 GB I want to create a new pst file and make it default. Able to get the pst file location as below.

But 1. how to identify current pst file 
2. how to create new pst file and make it default.

```
$outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$final=$outlook.Session.Stores | where { ($_.FilePath -like '*.pst')} | select FilePath 
$final
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get the default store you can use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm761)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) to get any default folder. Then you can use the [Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.store?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2016)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) property of the `Folder` class which returns a `Store` object representing the store that contains the Folder object.
2. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for changing the account settings (like stores). You need to use a low-level API (Extended MAPI) or any other third-party wrappers around that API. But you can add a new store by using the [AddStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstore?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm771)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) or [AddStoreEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstoreex?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm777)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) methods of the `Namespace` class.

```
Sub CreateUnicodePST()  
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace  

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 myNameSpace.AddStoreEx "c:\" & myNameSpace.CurrentUser & "\.pst",olStoreUnicode  
End Sub
```